# Create Soap XML on form submition in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a form, when user will submit that form, it will generate soap XML of that form and will send it to a third party with a username and password. And I am stuck on 1st step, I am trying to create XML according to that specific format but couldn't get any success, can anybody guide a little bit so I can move further on it. Here is a sample soap XML:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getPresaleByTNResponse xmlns="urn:OTSB2B">
            <getPresaleByTNReturn>
                <![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OTSB2B>
    <RequestDO>
        <StreetNum>123</StreetNum>
        <StreetSuf></StreetSuf>
        <StreetName>Forest</StreetName>
        <StreetType>DR</StreetType>
        <StreetDir></StreetDir>
        <LocationTypeA></LocationTypeA>
        <LocationValueA></LocationValueA>
        <LocationTypeB></LocationTypeB>
        <LocationValueB></LocationValueB>
        <City>Ottawa</City>
        <Province>on</Province>
        <PC>K1A1A1</PC>
    </RequestDO>
    <ResponseDO>
        <ServiceResponseTimestamp>2012-05-01-13-16-40</ServiceResponseTimestamp>
        <QueryInfo>
            <data key="AreServicesSupported" value="Yes"></data>
            <data key="FutureDate" value=""></data>
            <data key="ServiceSpeed" value="25.0"></data>
            <data key="ResBus" value="RES"></data>
            <data key="RemoteHost" value="Remote"></data>
            <data key="RateBand" value="C"></data>
            <data key="UploadSpeed" value="7.0"></data>
<data key="QualificationID" value="007213318"></data>
<data key="Network" value="FTTN"></data>
<data key="ProductList">
    <data key="Product" value="FTTN 10.0 with 1.0 upload"></data>
    <data key="Product" value="FTTN 15.0 with 1.0 upload"></data>
    <data key="Product" value="Legacy 6.0 with 0.800 upload"></data>
    <data key="Product" value="FTTN 7.0 with 1.0 upload"></data>
</data>
        </QueryInfo>
    </ResponseDO>
</OTSB2B>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to this page :  http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

You just have to use the PHP functions to generate your xml file.

Comment: I tried a lot, it is creating xml but just like this


<xml>
<OTSB2B>
<RequestDO>
<StreetNum>
 StreetNum
</StreetNum>
<City>
 Ottawa
</City>
</RequestDO>
</OTSB2B>
</xml>

can you tell me how to add this at top:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getPresaleByTNResponse xmlns="urn:OTSB2B">
            <getPresaleByTNReturn>
                <![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>